# Java: Output Array in Reverse Order

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and working with arrays.  Also new to this site.  Trying to output my array in reverse order:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListingTest
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    int length;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many names will you enter?");
    length = input.nextInt();

    String[] names = new String[length];
    int[] ages = new int[length];

    for(int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name " +(counter+1));
        names[counter] = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter age " +(counter+1));
        ages[counter] = input.nextInt();
    }

    input.close();

    for(int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++)
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " +names[counter]+ " Age: "+ages[counter]);
    }
  }
}
```

Having trouble with the last "for loop."  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: set counter to equal the length of your list, change `counter < length` to `counter>=0`and put `counter--` instead of `counter++`. This should start at (e.g 7) and count down to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = names.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
     System.out.println("Name: " + names[i] + " Age: " + ages[i]);
}
```

This starts at the top of the array and decrements i by 1 every iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had exactly what you have, but didn't have the "-1" after the length.

Comment: names.length should be changed to names.length-1. Otherwise, you will get an arrayOutOfBounds exception. Don't forget that an array with elements 0-4 will have a size 5, and array[5] is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Just  for printing Array at reversed order you have to use following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Or can use [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library:

> ArrayUtils.reverse(arr)